# Firebase Javascript Read From Database and Insert Each key into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Javascript project and am trying to read all the keys in my firebase database and inserting each and every entry into its own HTML heading. Although I have run into a problem where it is not working. What should I do? Here is the code.

```
function comment(){
    x = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    writeUserData(x);

}


message_id = 0;
function writeUserData(words) {
    database.ref('comments/' + String(message_id)).set({
        comment: words,
    });

    message_id ++;
}

function readComments(){
    var children;
    database.ref("comments/").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        children = snapshot.numChildren();
    })

    for (i = 0; i < children; i ++){
        database.ref('comments/' + String(i)).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var data = childSnapshot.val();

            //create html elements
            new_comment = document.createElement("H");
            new_comment.innerHTML = data;
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(new_comment);
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        });
        });
    }
}
```

Also, I am new to databases. So if there is perhaps a better way to write this code, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously. While that is happening, your main code continues to execute.

By the time your `for (i = 0; i < children; i ++){` now runs, the `children = snapshot.numChildren()` hasn't executed yet, so `children` has no value and the loop never enters.

The solution is *always* the same: any code that needs the data to the database, needs to be inside the callback that gets executed when the data has loaded.

So the simple solution is to move that code into the callback:

```
database.ref("comments/").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    children = snapshot.numChildren();
    for (i = 0; i < children; i ++){
        database.ref('comments/' + String(i)).on("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var data = childSnapshot.val();

            //create html elements
            new_comment = document.createElement("H");
            new_comment.innerHTML = data;
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(new_comment);
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          });
        });
    }
})
```

---

But I don't think you even need the nested `on()` call here, as all data is already loaded as part of `database.ref("comments/").on("value"`. All you need to do is loop over it in the callback, which should look something like:

```
database.ref("comments/").on("value", function(commentsSnapshot) {
    commentsSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var data = childSnapshot.val();

            //create html elements
            new_comment = document.createElement("H");
            new_comment.innerHTML = data;
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(new_comment);
            document.getElementById("comment_div").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, although it still has a problem. Every time I want to add to the database, when it reads back, the text also reads all the text added to the database. I may have not made sense so please let me know if it didn't. Ill send a screenshot. If you did understand, what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Given that you use `on("value"` that seems expected: `on()` means that you have a persistent listener that gets called again when the value it observes changes, and `"value"` means that you get called with a snapshot of all data at the path that you're observing (and not just what changed). You might want to consider either clearing `comment_div` before `commentsSnapshot.forEach(`, or listening to the relevant `child_` events. If you're having trouble making this work, please post a new question though, as I answered on why your loop was never entered to begin with.